# Why "Unable to add window -- token is invalid" exception comes?

Tags: android, webview

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@43e64670 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

When i try to show a dialog box i am getting this exception. why is this happening?

Comment: it often comes when you are using `TabGroupActivity`, because it cannot add the dialog to the child Activity.

Comment: I am not using TabGroupActivity.

Comment: then showing your code will help us better to identify the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Myactivity.this);
```

and if you have tabGroupactivity...

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Myactivity.this.getParent());
```